# 'button_to' gives me an ugly URL!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, helper

Im trying to get an 'add to cart' button to work.  When I use `<%= button_to "Add to Cart", :acton => "add_to_cart", :id => @product %>` and then click the button, I get a URL that puts the action after the ID, like this: `http://localhost:3000/store/show/1?acton=add_to_cart`  The cart page does not load.

What I need is a URL that looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/store/add_to_cart/1`.  I can get that result (and the cart to work) if I don't use 'button_to':

```
<% form_for @product, :url => {:action => "add_to_cart", :id => @product} do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Add to Cart' %></p>
<% end %>
```

But, what the heck?  Why can't I use `button_to`?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo? If your actual code also says `:acton` instead of `:action`, this might be the cause. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

in your button_to you should use **action**   instead of **acton**

like

```
<%= button_to "Add to Cart", :action => "add_to_cart", :id => @product %>
```

Comment: thanks guys for the time. the typo explanation is bittersweet. I stared at that for a good hour.